# I have Android Studio 1.0, can I safely remove the .AndroidStudioBeta folder?

Tags: android-studio

Now that I have `Android Studio 1.0`, could I safely delete `.AndroidStudioBeta` folder?

I noticed I had two distinct folders `.AndroidStudio` and `.AndroidStudioBeta`. My version of Android Studio is 1.0.x, so [it is not the beta any more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio). According to some [help page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963) linked in another question, I checked the `idea.properties` file and it links to the `.AndroidStudio` folder. I am wondering if there is any other place where such folder is referenced (and `.AndroidStudioBeta` might therefore still be used).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can safely delete it. The folder contains saved preferences and cache files, and would only be needed if you were still running the beta version for some reason. The only other reason to keep it hanging around is if you might want to migrate settings from the beta to the 1.0 version, but now that you're running 1.0 that's no longer necessary.

Deleting the folder will free up some disk space, so it's a good thing to do.

Comment: I confirm, I moved this away and I could use Android Studio without any problem, and the folder was not recreated.

Comment: Is this answer still valid for later versions. I have `.AndroidStudio1.2` , `.AndroidStudio1.3` and `.AndroidStudio1.4`  can I delete previous folders

Comment: @Zapnologica yes it is still valid

Comment: @Zapnologica @Vince @ScottBarta;  what about `.android` folder? Should I delete it? And, how is it different from `.AndroidStudio[version Number]` folders?

Comment: @AbhinavVutukuri do not delete that `.android` folder, it is still used by the current Android Studio (unlike the `.AndroidStudio[version]` folders)